# Bootstrap-tour won't work with a table row

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, bootstrap-tour

I'm trying to highlight a table row.
Even with this bootstrap-tour fix for z-indexes etc [github issue link](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/166#issuecomment-32213509)

Take a look at this fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYNbj/17/)

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#dialog").dialog(); 
var t = new Tour({
 backdrop: true,
 onShown: function(tour) {
    var stepElement = getTourElement(tour);
    $(stepElement).after($('.tour-step-background'));
    $(stepElement).after($('.tour-backdrop'));
},
steps: [
    {
        element: "table tbody tr:first-of-type",
        title: "Title",
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: "Content"
    }        
]
}).restart();


function getTourElement(tour){
   return tour._options.steps[tour._current].element
}
```

## HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Power</th>
            <th>Health</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Superman</td>
            <td>Flying</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Superman</td>
            <td>Flying</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Superman</td>
            <td>Flying</td>
            <td>100%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## CSS

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
.tour-step-background, 
.tour-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
}

.tour-step-background {
    background: #fff;
}
```

As you can see it won't show the (table row "tr") only if you change it's css to: `display:block;`
But then it will lose it's style.

Comment: You can resolve this by adding 'background: inherit; position: relative; z-index: 1101;' on '.tour-step-backdrop>td' as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/DYNbj/24/. The bootstrap-tour demo page shows the backdrop working on table, but it doesn't work with just a tr for some reason.

Comment: This is a solution for the problem. Why don't you put it up as an answer! Thank you!

Comment: OK, I went ahead and added it, but perhaps someone else might chime in with an explanation as to why td isn't inheriting these rules from tr and table in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding a rule

```
.tour-step-backdrop>td
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1101;
}
```

as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/DYNbj/24/